# MongoDB TTL not working due to time zone?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to get MongoDB to automatically delete documents using TTL, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is an example document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f50824169cb8055393c01e"),
    "_cls" : "ExpiringPageView",
    "viewable" : ObjectId("523f3586169cb81d568e442f"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2014-02-07T09:21:56.628Z")
}
```

And here are the indexes of the collection:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mysite.expiring_page_view",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_cls" : 1,
            "datetime" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mysite.expiring_page_view",
        "name" : "_cls_1_datetime_1",
        "background" : false,
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 60,
        "dropDups" : false
    }
]
```

I'm wondering if Mongo won't expire these documents due to the difference in time zone. When I enter `new ISODate()` in to the Mongo console I get a date/time that is 7 hours ahead (probably GMT) of the time in the document's `datetime` field. Could this be why my documents aren't expiring?

In case it helps, I'm using mongoengine as my document-object mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TTL index is a compound index, because it consists of both `_cls` and `datetime`, but that [is not supported](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/). Make sure the TTL index is a simple, non-compound index on `datetime` alone.

Comment: And in case anyone cares, I had to set `'allow_inheritance': False` in the Document in order to get mongoengine to not include `_cls` in the index `key`. Thanks mnemosyn!

Comment: And another note, the timezone was also an issue. Make sure the datetimes used in the documents are the same as the timezone that MongoDB is using

Comment: MongoDB servers (as many others) use UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB servers (as many others) use UTC ([Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)), you can get the correct time to set by coding:

```
from datetime import datetime

now_utc = datetime.utcnow()
# ...
collection.insert({'datetime': now_utc, ...})
```